# Every 7th item I get a duplicate because of my arrayadapter?

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, adapter

Every 7th time I get a duplicate item in my listview and it starts back from resulst nr 1 so this is my listview.

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4

I think it's because of my arrayadapter but I do not know where the fault is this is my adapter:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListEventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EventDetails> {

    public ListEventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<EventDetails> eItems;

    public ListEventAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<EventDetails> eItems) {

        super(context, resource, eItems);

        this.eItems = eItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        TextView txtAttending_count = null;
        TextView txtName = null;

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.event_item, null);

            txtAttending_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.attending_count);
            txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }

        EventDetails p = eItems.get(position);

        if (p != null) {

            if (txtAttending_count != null) {
                txtAttending_count.setText(""+p.getAttending_count());
            }
            if (txtName != null) {

                txtName.setText(""+p.getName());
            }
        }



        return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: don't know I didnt do it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized. The answer won't help anyone else, ever.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to know how often I got this wrong before I finally learned :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txtAttending_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.attending_count);
txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Those two lines should be outside the if.
Now you are only assigning these fields if you are creating a new view. If you are reusing a view that has scrolled out of the screen, which is what is probably happens given that it occurs "every 7th time", `txtAttending_count` and `txtName` remain `null` and you never update them with the new value, which means you get to see the original view again.

Comment: OMG thank you! Why didnt I come up with this. Need some sleep I guess. Thanks you!!